# The console is breaking when it reaches a point in this 2d array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I wanted to make a simple 2d array. Just wanted to build a project in which I present how to find the max value in an array. It was a part of my project. But when I finished the first part of it, suddenly found out that the console was breaking when I tried filling in the numbers of the array. Might be a problem with my Dev C++, tho it didn't compile at all in the Code Blocks and it broke even earlier in the online compiler. Can anyone give me at least a hint at what may be causing this problem. I also put an cout statement so that I can see where exactly does it break, the answer was  before the final or second-to-final row loop. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    int a[n][m];
    cout<<"Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin>>m;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
           cout<<"a["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] = ";
           cin>>a[i][j];
           cout<<"j loop"<<endl;;
        }
        cout<<"i loop"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a[n][m]` is a nonstandard extension supported by some compilers. Don't use it. You're also accessing `n` and `m` with uninitialized values, so you have undefined behavior.

Comment: `int n, m; int a[n][m];` is meaningless, for more than one reason. First, variable length arrays are not a part of C++. Use std::vector instead. Second, it looks like you expect that `a[n][m];` will track changes in `n` and `m` and automatically adjust the size accordingly. This is not what happens. The current value is used, and there is none, because you did not initialise n and m.

Comment: In C++, whenever you think "dynamic array" your next thought should almost always be [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible it C++.
First of all, it's impossible to tell program that matrix will be n by m without knowing n and m as you did not assign any value to them. Second, even if you assign values, you will still get errors as arrays in c++ cannot have variables like that. What you need is dynamic array and your code would look like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    int **a;
    cout<<"Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin>>m;
    a = new int*[n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i] = new int[m];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
           cout<<"a["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] = ";
           cin>>a[i][j];
           cout<<"j loop"<<endl;;
        }
        cout<<"i loop"<<endl;
    }
    for (int i=0;i=0;i<n){
        delete a[i];
    }
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

Where a is now dynamic matrix, or array of arrays. It will not get deleted automatically, so you must explicitly call delete on it. For each array and then for array of arrays itself.